How to resolve ECONNRESET Error in a Raspberry Pi Pico W Micropython that uses MQTT
I'm working on a project using a Raspberry Pi. There are two main files involved: wifimgr.py and mqtt_client.py. wifimgr.py acts as a WiFi Manager, allowing me to set up the device to connect to a nearby wireless network (WLAN). mqtt_client.py is, as the name implies, an MQTT client, which connects to a Mosquitto broker to send data.
However, I'm encountering an issue specifically within mqtt_client.py. I suspect the problem lies in the connect method of umqtt.simple:
mqttClient.connect()

The error message I'm getting is:
[Errno 104] ECONNRESET

I'm not entirely certain, but I think another potential cause of the problem could be related to wifimgr.py. When connecting to the WLAN in that file, the access point (AP) might remain active for a short period before the connection is completely deactivated.
I'm still relatively new to socket programming, so I'm in the process of learning more about it.
I haven't put in much effort to resolve this problem because it only occurs sporadically. I'm not sure why, but after waiting for a few hours, everything seems to work fine again. However, the error resurfaces the next day, despite my attempts to address it by restarting the wireless network, relocating the code, and so on.
Here is the content of the files I mentioned and main.py which serves as the intermediary:
# main.py
import time
from machine import Pin
from mqtt_client import run_mqtt_client
from wifimgr import Wifimgr
from io import reset_secrets

LED = Pin("LED", Pin.OUT)
LED.off()

def main():
    wifi_manager = Wifimgr()
    wifi_manager.ap_mode()
    retries = 0
    if wifi_manager.credentials.SSID and wifi_manager.credentials.PWD and wifi_manager.credentials.BROKER_IP:
        while True:
            if (wifi_manager.verify_wlan_if()):
                LED.on()
                try:
                    BROKER_IP, BROKER_USR, BROKER_PWD, SUB_T, PUB_T = wifi_manager.credentials.get_mqtt_params()
                    print('Running mqtt client...', BROKER_IP, BROKER_USR, BROKER_PWD, SUB_T, PUB_T)
                    run_mqtt_client(BROKER_IP, BROKER_USR, BROKER_PWD)
                    wifi_manager.manage_wlan_if(wifi_manager.DEACTIVATE_INTERFACE)
                except OSError as e:
                    print("Error: " + str(e))
                    LED.off()
                    
                    wifi_manager.manage_wlan_if(wifi_manager.DEACTIVATE_INTERFACE)
                    time.sleep(3)
                    wifi_manager.manage_wlan_if(wifi_manager.ACTIVATE_INTERFACE)
                    
                    if retries > 3:
                        reset_secrets(wifi_manager.credentials)
                        print('secrets have been reseted')
                        break
                    retries += 1
                    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# Wifimgr.py
import network
import time
import socket
from html import get_webpage
from io import Credentials, write_secrets, read_secrets, reset_secrets
import machine

MIN_RSSI = -67
LED = machine.Pin("LED", machine.Pin.OUT)

class Wifimgr:
    def __init__(self, ap_ssid=b'RBPPIW', ap_pwd=b'defaultpass', debug=True):
        self.ap_ssid = ap_ssid
        self.ap_pwd = ap_pwd
        self.debug = debug
        
        self.credentials = Credentials()

        self.ap_if = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF) # Access Point Interface
        self.wlan_if = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF) # Wlan Interface
        
        # Deactivate both interfaces
        self.ap_if.active(False)
        self.wlan_if.active(False)

        self.URL_ENCODE = {
            ...
        }
        
        self.ACTIVATE_INTERFACE = 1
        self.DEACTIVATE_INTERFACE = 0

    def __decode_url_syntax(self, encoded):
        ...
    
    def __parse_form_data(self, request):
        ...

    def __scan_wlan(self):
        ...
    
    def __connect_to_network(self, ssid, pwd):
        self.wlan_if.active(True)
        self.wlan_if.connect(ssid, pwd)
        seconds = 0
        while not self.wlan_if.isconnected():
            if seconds > 10:
                if self.debug:
                    print('Failed to connect to the network.')
                self.wlan_if.active(False)
                return False
            if self.debug:
                print('Trying to connect to ' + ssid + '.')
            time.sleep(1)
            seconds += 1
        LED.on()
        if self.debug:
            print('Connected to network: ', ssid, ' | Network config: ', self.wlan_if.ifconfig())
        return True

    def ap_mode(self):
        read_secrets(self.credentials)
        if (self.credentials.SSID and self.credentials.PWD and self.credentials.BROKER_IP):
            if self.debug:
                print('Stored credentials found: ', self.credentials)
            if (self.__connect_to_network(self.credentials.SSID, self.credentials.PWD)):
                if self.debug:
                    print('Connection successfull.')
                return True
            else:
                reset_secrets()
                if self.debug:
                    print('Bad credentials. reseting device in 5 seconds...')
                time.sleep(5)
                machine.reset()
        reset_secrets()
        
        self.ap_if.config(essid=self.ap_ssid, password=self.ap_pwd)
        self.ap_if.active(True)
        
        scanned_wlans = self.__scan_wlan() # (ssid, bssid, channel, RSSI, security, hidden)
        ssids = []
        for scanned_wlan in scanned_wlans:
            ssid, _ = scanned_wlan
            ssids.append(ssid.decode('utf-8'))
        
        while not self.ap_if.active():
            pass
        if self.debug:
            print('AP mode activated: ' + self.ap_if.ifconfig()[0])
        
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.bind(('', 80))
        s.listen(1)
        while True:
            conn, _ = s.accept()
            request = conn.recv(1024)   
            if (self.credentials.SSID and self.credentials.PWD and self.credentials.BROKER_IP):
                if (self.__connect_to_network(self.credentials.SSID, self.credentials.PWD)):
                    conn.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<h1>Success!</h1>')
                    conn.close()
                    self.ap_if.active(False)
                    if self.debug:
                        print('AP handler has finished.')
                    break
            self.__parse_form_data(request)
            conn.send(get_webpage(ssids))
            conn.close()
        return True

    def manage_wlan_if(self, mode):
        self.wlan_if.active(mode)
    
    def manage_ap_if(self, mode):
        self.ap_if.active(mode)
        
    def verify_wlan_if(self):
        return self.wlan_if.isconnected()
    
    def verify_ap_if(self, mode):
        return self.ap_if.isconnected()

# mqtt_client.py
import time
import ubinascii
from umqtt.simple import MQTTClient
import machine
import random

# Default  MQTT_BROKER to connect to
CLIENT_ID = ubinascii.hexlify(machine.unique_id())

# Setup built in PICO LED as Output
led = machine.Pin("LED",machine.Pin.OUT)

# Publish MQTT messages after every set timeout
last_publish = time.time()
publish_interval = 5

# Received messages from subscriptions will be delivered to this callback
def sub_cb(topic, msg):
    print((topic, msg))
    if msg.decode() == "ON":
        led.value(1)
    else:
        led.value(0)
        
def reset():
    print("Resetting...")
    time.sleep(5)
    machine.reset()
    
# Generate dummy random temperature readings    
def get_temperature_reading():
    return random.randint(20, 50)
    
def run_mqtt_client(BROKER_IP, BROKER_USR, BROKER_PWD, SUB_T = 'sub/default', PUB_T = 'pub/default'):
    print(f"Begin connection with MQTT Broker :: {BROKER_IP}")
    mqttClient = MQTTClient(CLIENT_ID, BROKER_IP, keepalive=120)
    mqttClient.set_callback(sub_cb)
    mqttClient.connect()  # I believe here is where the error raises
    mqttClient.subscribe(SUB_T)
    print(f'Device subscribed to topic: ', SUB_T)
    print(f'Device publishing to topic: ', PUB_T)
    print(f"Connected to MQTT  Broker :: {BROKER_IP}, and waiting for callback function to be called!")
    while True:
            # Non-blocking wait for message
            mqttClient.check_msg()
            global last_publish
            if (time.time() - last_publish) >= publish_interval:
                random_temp = get_temperature_reading()
                print(random_temp)
                mqttClient.publish(PUB_T, str(random_temp).encode())
                last_publish = time.time()
            time.sleep(1)


Start by having your code print the full stack trace of the error, such that you know what exactly goes wrong where.
